# Adding multiple pieces of data to a single row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a website that imports JSON data and populates a table within HTML. In this instance the JSON file has already been parsed and exists as an JavaScript object.

I am having trouble iterating through the arrays within the object to try and add data with different key values to a single table row.

what I want to achieve is to have the names of each employee who works in a particular department to be present in a single row.

I started by creating an empty array outside my for loops.
I have iterated through the object using three separate for loops and appended the names of the employees to this empty array. After my loops i have let my now full array that contains the names equal to an empty array.
What i have been working on can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/kn0y9g5d/

```
<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
const table =
  { "Employees": 
    [ { "Started"   : "2016"
      , "Department": "Engineering"
      , "Employee": 
        [ { "id": "a101", "firstname": "Alan",  "surname": "Arkin"  } 
        , { "id": "a102", "firstname": "Geoff", "surname": "keegan" } 
        ] 
      } 
    , { "Started"   : "2016"
      , "Department": "R&D"
      , "Employee": 
        [ { "id": "a103", "firstname": "Michele", "surname": "Jones" } 
        , { "id": "a104", "firstname": "Peter",   "surname": "Smith" } 
        ] 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
var DepName =[];
var employeeNames =[];
let MyTable = document
                .querySelector('#id01')
                .appendChild(document.createElement('table'))

for (let StartDep of table.Employees)
  {
  for (let Employee of StartDep.Employee )
    {
    for (let Employee1 of StartDep.Employee ){
        var name = Employee1.firstname + " " + Employee1.surname
      employeeNames.push(name)
    let nRow = MyTable.insertRow(-1)
      , rCell  = 0
    nRow.insertCell(rCell++).textContent = StartDep.Started
    nRow.insertCell(rCell++).textContent = StartDep.Department
    nRow.insertCell(rCell++).textContent = employeeNames

     }employeeNames=[];
    }
  }

let Rowhead = MyTable.createTHead().insertRow(-1)

'Started,Department,Name(s)'.split(',')
  .forEach((T,i)=>Rowhead.insertCell(i).textContent=T)
</script>
```

what I expect to get using this code will be similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgvlo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

console.log(table);

```
const abc = [];
for(var j=0;j<2;j++)
{
  const gh = [];
  for(var i =0;i<2;i++)
  {
    let name = table.Employees[j].Employee[i].firstname+" "+table.Employees[j].Employee[i].surname
    gh.push(name);
  }
  var totalName = gh.join();
  abc.push(totalName);
}

console.log(table.Employees[0].Employee[0].firstname);
console.log(abc);
```

if you do this before appending this to table you should be able to get the result easily
i did it on my own so i cant give you any reference to look at.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi thank you where would I append this data to my table

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rc8x1jek/9/
here the table looks exactly like in the image and i took ur code in jsfddler and made changes your for loop thats all